# Issue with import pyximport in Sagemaker jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, importerror, amazon-sagemaker, cpython, modulenotfounderror

[I manually install CPython again but for some reason, a file in my program is not able to import pyximport in a Sagemaker notebook instance .ipynb file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nH85.png)

Any ideas what's going on?